# Changing slides at specified hours/minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I'm working on a project where the target is to present information at a big screen on a festival. The main concern is to get the proper content showing at the proper time, i.e. the next band playing and so on. There's also going to be different information depending on the time of day.

I'm eager to create something I can alter remotely, i.e. if there's any changes to the program. When the concerts are going on, video from live cameras will be projected on the screen, so I have a lot of opportunities to alter the content and refreshing the page without anyone noticing.

jQuery Cycle and other slideshow scripts is doing a lot of the job, but I haven't mananged to find any solutions that offer other settings then certain intervals. Which would not work in this case, since a simple refresh then would break the whole thing...

To sum it up, what I'm looking for is a solution that can make this happen:

- Aug 2nd 6:03:30: Show slide 1
- Aug 2nd 6:05:00: Show slide 2
- Aug 2nd 6:10:00: Show slide 3

...and so on

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?  http://jsfiddle.net/pMXNQ/